# Повреждена флешка

Tags: linux, windows, восстановление, внешние-устройства

Доброе время суток. Решил защитить флешку Corsair Flash Voyager Mini с помощью Bitlocker, зашифровал, работала как положено. После решил попробовать разблокировать флешку в Linux с помощью определённых программ, но там она перестала определятся как что-либо. Ни в GParted, ни где-либо ещё. Только в стандартной утилите "Диски", но там она отображалась как дисковод, а не флеш-память.
Собственно, теперь и в Windows она определяется как дисковод, а не флешка. Её невозможно форматировать (даже через терминал и консоль), изменить разделы и "спасти" с помощью других утилит - её якобы не существует. Определяется в Диспетчере устройств как отдельное устройство, "нормально работающее". В Управлении дисками также отображается, но сделать что-либо с ней нельзя.
Вопрос: что делать и возможно ли спасти флешку?

Comment: Т.е. ты решил поэксперементировать с проприетарной технологией хранения с данными в единственном экземпляре на этой самой флэшке?

Comment: Я писал о данных? Вроде нет. Я лишь писал, что зашифровал её. Вопрос о "спасении" флешки предполагал не спасения данных, а спасения её самой.

Comment: `Я писал о данных? Вроде нет.` - не зная всех переменных окружения невозможно корректно советовать что-либо дальше.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd{encrypted-flash}` пробовал?

Comment: Я описал проблему так подробно, насколько это возможно. Разницы в том, была ли "информация в единственном экземпляре" на флешке или нет для меня нет. Мне важно восстановить флешку, а не то, что там осталось. Хотя, там уже ничего нет.

Comment: Команду, которую вы предложили я попробую и отпишусь. Но боюсь, она не поможет, ибо Linux её (флешку) просто не видит, кроме утилиты "Диски", что установлена по умолчанию. Windows же, в отличие от сторонних программ, её видит, но как "дисковод", требуя вставить диск внутрь него, и как пустое устройство в утилите **diskpart**, с отсутствующим медиа-пространством. Команда **clean** сообщает об этой проблеме и не может форматировать флешку.

Comment: Это даёт мне лишний раз убедиться, что флешки no-name'ов и такие, вроде Corsair, покупать не стоит. Если ты купил эту флешку, можно попробовать заменить её по гарантии, но именно **заменить**, а не **починить**. Уж тем более я её не купил, а нашел работающей. У них даже нет фирменной утилиты для воскрешения флешек. Отремонтировать её физически тоже вряд-ли удастся по причине её монолитности.

Comment: У карточек свой процессор и своя прошивка, в зависимости от них и от команд, которые перед этим посылались, можно с разной степенью вероятности её восстановить.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` чё выдаёт?

Comment: В том то и дело, что нихрена не выдаёт!

Comment: Тут коллега подсказывает `Flash Drive Information Extractor` и `ChipGenius`, http://flashboot.ru/files/utility/

Comment: Окей, попробую, отпишусь, но не уверен.
UPD: В программе пусто. Я думаю, флешка сгорела после подключения к ПК. Другие мои флешки - нет. Во всяком случае, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Флешки Corsair и другие no-name непригодны для использования на ПК. Это даёт мне повод сделать свой выбор в пользу A-брендов. Сгорела чертовка, в отличие от того же Kingston.